# opencv_createsamples doesn't work correctly

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier, opencv3.1

I'm using opencv-3.3.1 on windows. I have a 'pos' file containing my positive images and a file called 'info.txt' which contains the address, number and the coordinates of object in positive images.

In order to make a .vec file I use this command:

```
opencv_createsamples -info info.txt -num 1000 -w 100 -h 100 -vec car.vec
```

To test the vec file I use this command:

```
opencv_createsamples -w 100 -h 100 -vec car.vec
```

But the output of the command is not correct it's look like that the coordinates in vec file isn't correct. I have checked the info file several times and it is accurate.(but I have tried it on Linux Ubuntu too)
Here is my info.txt file:

```
pos/1.jpg 1 80 146 164 163
.....
.....
```

The question is why the output isn't correct while the coordinates are true or how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is why the output isn't correct while the coordinates are true or how can I fix it?

Comment: what do you mean by "I have a 'pos' file containing my positive images"? Do you mean a "pos folder"?

Comment: can you add information about your directory structure and how/where you start createsamples (working directory)? In my case I use the following and it works: createsample is in directory `X`. pos.txt is in `X/ANYNAME` positive samples are in `X/ANYNAME/pos` pos.txt consists of entries like the one you posted. Starting `..\opencv_createsamples.exe -info pos.txt ` in working directory `X/ANYNAME/`

Comment: In your info.txt, you know that 80 146 164 163 means starting point (col=80,row=146) with a width of 164 and a height of 163, right (not starting point and ending point, but starting point and size)?